# How to split strings inside a list by given delimiter and flatten the sub-strings lists

Tags: python, string, list, flatten

I have a python script with this list:

```
blocks = [
  "item-1",
  "item-2",
  "item-3.0;item-3.1;item-3.2"
]
```

I have tried this:

```
for (i, block) in enumerate(blocks):
  if ";" in block:
    [blocks.insert(i, c) for c in block.split(";")]
  else:
    blocks.insert(i, block)
```

To get this:

```
blocks = [
  "item-1",
  "item-2",
  "item-3.0",
  "item-3.1",
  "item-3.2"
]
```

Unfortunately my code keeps overwriting the the elements in the list, and I'm left with this:

```
blocks = [
  "item-1",
  "item-2",
  "item-3.2"
]
```

How can I modify the script to allow me to split a string inside of a list and then insert the new sub-strings into the position of the original string without overwriting the other elements in the list?

Comment: Why don't have a new list, append them all in a new list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be easier to make a new list:

```
blocks = [
  "item-1",
  "item-2",
  "item-3.0;item-3.1;item-3.2"
]

new_blocks = []

for block in blocks:
    for c in block.split(";"):
        new_blocks.append(c)

 # new_blocks = ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-3.0', 'item-3.1', 'item-3.2']
```

Answer (score 8):

You may achieve this via using *nested list comprehension* expression:

```
blocks = [
   "item-1",
   "item-2",
   "item-3.0;item-3.1;item-3.2"
]

my_list = [a for b in blocks for a in b.split(';')]
```

where content hold by `my_list` will be:

```
['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-3.0', 'item-3.1', 'item-3.2']
```

Answer (score 5):

split will return a list, you don't need to check if ';' is in the block:

```
In [34]: [ii.split(';') for ii in blocks]
Out[34]: [['item-1'], ['item-2'], ['item-3.0', 'item-3.1', 'item-3.2']]
```

So now the only thing you need is to add all the list together, with the function sum.

```
sum( [ii.split(';') for ii in blocks] ,  [])
```

Comment: [`sum()` is not recommended for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952946/4518341) You could use a [nested list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/4518341) instead.

Comment: Agreed, for long lists, it would not be efficient. I find nested list comprehensions... difficult to comprehend :p

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new list to hold the results instead of modifying the original list while looping through it:

```
result = []
for block in blocks:
    result.extend(block.split(";"))

result
# ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-3.0', 'item-3.1', 'item-3.2']
```

---

Inspired by @Jblasco's answer, you can also use `chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable(block.split(';') for block in blocks))

# ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-3.0', 'item-3.1', 'item-3.2']
```

Answer (score 0):

in place editing of lists while iterating over it is not a good idea.

As the other answers say, make a new list. If you're into list comprehensions (and make your head explode a little), try this:

```
blocks = [
  "item-1",
  "item-2",
  "item-3.0;item-3.1;item-3.2"
]
[substr for block in blocks for substr in block.split(';')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
';'.join(blocks).split(';')
```

out:

```
['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-3.0', 'item-3.1', 'item-3.2']
```

Just `join` the list together and `split` again.

And in the [Document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), `sum` a list is not recommended:

> For some use cases, there are good alternatives to sum(). The
>   preferred, fast way to concatenate a sequence of strings is by calling
>   ''.join(sequence). To add floating point values with extended
>   precision, see math.fsum(). **To concatenate a series of iterables,
>   consider using `itertools.chain()`.**