# How to split strings inside a list by whitespace characters

Tags: python, string, list, split

So stdin returns a string of text into a list, and multiple lines of text are all list elements.
How do you split them all into single words?

```
mylist = ['this is a string of text \n', 'this is a different string of text \n', 'and for good measure here is another one \n']
```

wanted output:

```
newlist = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'of', 'text', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'different', 'string', 'of', 'text', 'and', 'for', 'good', 'measure', 'here', 'is', 'another', 'one']
```

Comment: Related: [How to split strings inside a list by given delimiter and flatten the sub-strings lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41700349/7851470).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use simple list comprehension, like:

```
newlist = [word for line in mylist for word in line.split()]
```

This generates:

```
>>> [word for line in mylist for word in line.split()]
['this', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'of', 'text', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'different', 'string', 'of', 'text', 'and', 'for', 'good', 'measure', 'here', 'is', 'another', 'one']
```

Answer (score 6):

You could just do:

```
words = str(list).split()
```

So you turn the list into a string then split it by a space bar.
Then you can remove the /n's by doing:

```
words.replace("/n", "")
```

Or if you want to do it in one line:

```
words = str(str(str(list).split()).replace("/n", "")).split()
```

Just saying this may not work in python 2

Answer (score 3):

Besides the list comprehension answer above that i vouch for, you could also do it in a for loop:

```
#Define the newlist as an empty list
newlist = list()
#Iterate over mylist items
for item in mylist:
 #split the element string into a list of words
 itemWords = item.split()
 #extend newlist to include all itemWords
 newlist.extend(itemWords)
print(newlist)
```

eventually your `newlist` will contain all split words that were in all elements in `mylist`

But the python list comprehension looks much nicer and you can do awesome things with it. Check here for more:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Yes, thanks for putting me onto this, I was studying it all weekend. It is a nice and elegant way to solve the problem. My main concern is speed and efficiency, and it seems to me that list comprehensions being part of the built in python language would be quicker than a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method to every string inside the list and then chain the elements from the resulting lists together by [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

mylist = ['this is a string of text \n', 'this is a different string of text \n', 'and for good measure here is another one \n']
result = list(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, mylist)))
print(result)
# ['this', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'of', 'text', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'different', 'string', 'of', 'text', 'and', 'for', 'good', 'measure', 'here', 'is', 'another', 'one']
```