# Splitting words in a list

Tags: python, split

How to split a list into separate words. I know that you can split strings with `split` but I need to split a list.

**Here is my code:**

```
text = ['a,b', 'c,d']
text = text.replace(',', ' ')
for i in text:
  print(text.split())
```

When I run it, an error pops up and when I try to convert the list into a string there are random extras like **\n**, **'** and **[]** that shouldn't be there.

**Expected result:** I want the outcome to be a list that contains ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] that when I print, comes up with that.

The error comes up on line two and says:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python how to split text already in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085616/python-how-to-split-text-already-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can do that easily but first you should read what does the [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) function exactly do.

```
newList = []
for i in text:
    words = i.split(',')
    newList.extend(words)
print(newList)
```

Here are some useful information, [Python list extend](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/extend), [Iterating over a list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/).

**Plus**, There is no method called `replace` for `list`s, this method works for `String`s.

Answer (score 2):

```
your_list = [ x for sublist in text for x in sublist.split(',') ]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `replace` function for a list. I guess what you want is to split on comma:

```
text = ['a,b', 'c,d']
result = []
for i in text:
  result.extend(i.split(','))
```

Note the second change I did is to print `i` - the thing that iterates as opposed to the whole `text`. Additionally I am calling `extend` on the result to produce a single list.

Answer (score 1):

One more approach:

```
text = ['a,b', 'c,d']
text = ','.join(text)
text = text.split(',')
print(text)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do to the following:

```
text = ['a,b', 'c,d']
text_str = "".join(text).replace(",", "")
arr = [c for c in text_str]
```

its a bit verbose, but those are the steps

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> text = ['a,b', 'c,d']
>>> list(chain(*[item.split(',') for item in text]))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```