# Cursor cannot update field because of IndexError

Tags: python, list, split, arcpy

I'm using `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` to update the `UnitName` field with an element from a list. I largely based my script off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085616/how-to-split-strings-inside-a-list-by-whitespace-characters).

This executes successfully:

```
import arcpy

#fields from the feature class table
field = ['Unit', 'UnitName']

#use a cursor to parse the table of the feature class
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: 
        unit = row[0] #get Unit in field list
        s = str(unit).split() #split strings in Unit field 
        print(s) #print list
```

Here are a few examples of what prints out:

```
['200']
['STE', '112']
['STE', 'L']
['UNIT', 'A']
['STE', 'B']
['STE', 'A']
['None']
['None']
```

But, when I put an index number on the print statement I get the `IndexError: list index out of range`. Funny thing is I don't get the error right away. A bunch of elements are printed before the error occurs. I think it is because of the `None` elements.

```
import arcpy

#fields from the feature class table
field = ['Unit', 'UnitName']

#use a cursor to parse the table of the feature class
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: 
        unit = row[1] #get Unit in field list
        s = str(unit).split() #split strings in Unit field 
        print(s[1]) #print element in second position
        row[1] = s[1] #create variable for the element
        cursor.updateRow(row) #use cursor to update "UnitName" field with element in second position
```

```
200
112
L
A
B
A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\GISstaff\Jared\Python Scripts\ArcGISPro\USPS_ADDRE_copy.py", line 40, in <module>
    unitname()
  File "\GISstaff\Jared\Python Scripts\ArcGISPro\USPS_ADDRE_copy.py", line 34, in unitname
    print(s[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by accessing the last item in the list as opposed to the second.

This:

`print(s[-1]) #prints None elements too`

Not this:

`print(s[1])`