# Split and flatten a list of strings

Tags: python, list

```
lst = [
  "Zambia",
  "Zimbabwe",
  "Suite,203,2880,Zanker,Rd,San,Jose,95134",
  "1496A,1st,and,2nd,Floor,19th,main,8th,crossSector,1,HSR,Layout,Bengaluru,560102",
]
```

Here I have a list of words. Some are actual words like `"Zambia"` and some are sentences like `"Suite,203,2880,Zanker,Rd,San,Jose,95134"`.

How can I convert them into the below format?

```
lst = [
  "Zambia",
  "Zimbabwe",
  "Suite",
  "203",
  "2880",
  "Zanker",
  "Rd",
  "San",
  "Jose",
  "95134",
  "1496A",
  "1st",
  "and",
  "2nd",
  "Floor",
  "19th",
  "main",
  "8th",
  "crossSector",
  "1",
  "HSR",
  "Layout",
  "Bengaluru",
  "560102",
  "g2crowd_badge2",
  "Created with Sketch."
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I split a string inside of a list and flatten the sub-strings list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700349/how-can-i-split-a-string-inside-of-a-list-and-flatten-the-sub-strings-list)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try:

```
res = []    
for i in lst:
   res.extend(i.split(","))
```

Another option is to use `reduce`:

```
res = list(reduce(lambda a, b: a + b.split(','), lst, []))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a list comprehension and [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) each string. Finally flatten the result with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*[i.split(',') for i in lst]))

['Zambia', 'Zimbabwe', 'Suite', '203', '2880', 'Zanker', 'Rd', 'San', 'Jose', 
 '95134', '1496A', '1st', 'and', '2nd', 'Floor', '19th', 'main', '8th', 
 'crossSector', '1', 'HSR', 'Layout', 'Bengaluru', '560102']
```

Answer (score 3):

Given `lst` = your list above

`flattened_list = [item for sublist in lst for item in sublist.split(",")]`

---

Sources

- [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/3679900)
- [Python string split()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)